# discord bot autorole -- in _run_event yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am new to Python and have some issues with my Discord Bot which I do not get fixed. The bot should automatically assign roles to users who join the server for the first time. I can set up autorole successfully. But when a user joins the server, the following error message appears in the console.

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:/dev/DiscordBot/main.py", line 35, in on_member_join
    await client.add_role(member, role)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 296, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(msg.format(self.__class__, name))
AttributeError: '<class 'discord.client.Client'>' object has no attribute 'add_role'
C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:314: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get' was never awaited
  pass
```

main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import SECRETS
import STATICS
from commands import cmd_autorole

client = discord.Client()

commands = dict(autorole=cmd_autorole)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="with humans"))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(STATICS.PREFIX):
        invoke = message.content[len(STATICS.PREFIX):].split(" ")[0]
        args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
        if commands.__contains__(invoke):
            await commands.get(invoke).ex(args, message, client, invoke)
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=("The command `%s` is not valid!" % invoke)))


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    # await client.send_message(member, "**Hello %s,**\n\nwelcome on Discord-Server __**%s**__!\nPlease look first at the main channel %s .\n\nHave Fun!" % (member.name, member.server.name, discord.utils.get(member.server.channels, id="532425431526277135").mention))
    role = cmd_autorole.get(member.server)
    if not role is None:
        await client.add_role(member, role)


client.run(SECRETS.TOKEN)
```

cmd_autorole.py

```
import os
from os import path

import discord


async def error(content, channel, client):
    await client.send_message(channel, embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=content))


async def get(server):
    f = "SETTINGS/" + server.id + "/autorole"
    if path.isfile(f):
        with open(f) as f:
            return discord.utils.get(server.roles, id=f.read())
    else:
        return None


async def savefile(id, server):
    if not path.isdir("SETTINGS/" + server.id):
        os.makedirs("SETTINGS/" + server.id)
    with open("SETTINGS/" + server.id + "/autorole", "w") as f:
        f.write(id)
        f.close()


async def ex(args, message, client, invoke):
    print(args)
    if len(args) > 0:
        rolename = args.__str__()[1:-1].replace(",", "").replace("'", "")
        role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=rolename)
        if role is None:
            await error("Please enter a valid role existing on this server!", message.channel, client)
        else:
            try:
                await savefile(role.id, message.server)
                await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green(), description=("Autorole has been successfully set up for the Role `% s`." % role.name)))
            except Exception:
                await error("Something went wrong while saving autorole!", message.channel, client)
                raise Exception
```

Comment: It's [`Client.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles) not `add_role`.

Comment: Hello Patrick Haugh,
thanks a lot for the quick response and the help. I changed line 35 to client.add_roles, but there are still errors.
For example, the last error message that 'get' was never awaited. I can not find my mistake.

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:/dev/DiscordBot/main.py", line 35, in on_member_join
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2915, in add_roles
    new_roles = utils._unique(role.id for role in itertools.chain(member.roles, roles))

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 232, in _unique
    return [x for x in iterable if not (x in seen or adder(x))]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 232, in <listcomp>
    return [x for x in iterable if not (x in seen or adder(x))]
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'id'
C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:314: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get' was never awaited
  pass

Comment: `cmd_autorole.get` is a coroutine and needs to be `await`ed

Comment: I've also noticed it in the meantime and changed, it now runs without errors. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

In your `cmd_autorole.py` file, the `get()` function is asynchronous, but **you haven't awaited it** in your main file.
You must to write `role = await cmd_autorole.get(member.server)` instead of `role = cmd_autorole.get(member.server)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@client.event` for the second events try using `@client.listen`like this:

```py
@client.listen
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(STATICS.PREFIX):
        invoke = message.content[len(STATICS.PREFIX):].split(" ")[0]
        args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
        if commands.__contains__(invoke):
            await commands.get(invoke).ex(args, message, client, invoke)
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=("The command `%s` is not valid!" % invoke)))


@client.listen
async def on_member_join(member):
    # await client.send_message(member, "**Hello %s,**\n\nwelcome on Discord-Server __**%s**__!\nPlease look first at the main channel %s .\n\nHave Fun!" % (member.name, member.server.name, discord.utils.get(member.server.channels, id="532425431526277135").mention))
    role = cmd_autorole.get(member.server)
    if not role is None:
        await client.add_role(member, role)
```